# TypeScript error in @mui/material/styles/experimental_extendTheme.d.ts(313,9):

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Typescript error after use material UI component date rage picker

Link - https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/

code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/AdapterDayjs';
import { StaticDateRangePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/StaticDateRangePicker';
import { DateRange } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/DateRangePicker';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function StaticDateRangePickerDemo() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<DateRange<Dayjs>>([null, null]);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <StaticDateRangePicker
        displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <TextField {...startProps} />
            <Box sx={{ mx: 2 }}> to </Box>
            <TextField {...endProps} />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

printscreen bellow

```
Failed to compile.

TypeScript error in C:/Users/jonathas/projetos/portal-cliente-frontend/node_modules/@mui/material/styles/experimental_extendTheme.d.ts(313,9):
Type expected.  TS1110

    311 |       ? keyof T
    312 |       : keyof V extends string | number
  > 313 |       ? `${keyof T}-${ConcatDeep<Split<V>>}`
        |         ^
    314 |       : never
    315 |     : never
    316 |   : never;
```

[image]

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "portal-cliente-atem",
  "version": "0.1.101",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@datadog/browser-rum": "^4.23.3",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.x",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fontsource/montserrat": "^4.5.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.7",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro": "^5.0.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/babel__core": "^7.1.20",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.8",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "framer-motion": "^8.4.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.14.1",
    "inversify": "^5.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "keycloak-js": "^11.0.2",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "notistack": "^1.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.68",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-json-view": "^1.19.1",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.1.1",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
    "start:prod": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='production' react-app-rewired start",
    "start:homologation": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='homologation' react-app-rewired start",
    "build:homologation": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='homologation' react-app-rewired build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.groupby": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.throttle": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.7",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.7"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same error. Updating typescript from 3.9.7 to 4.9.5 (latest) seem to fix this.